# Chrome allocation timeline profiler - objects in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, memory-profiling

Are object sections in parenthesis (ie. (array), (system), (closure)), captured by the chrome allocation profiler, possible to be collected by garbage collector? I mean a situation where there exists permanent reference to those objects so that the GC is not able to collect them.

I've read that the sections like (compiled code) and (system) can be ignored.

In other words - which kind of objects in the "Constructor" tab are a sign of a memory leak?

Comment: Any object is garbage collectable if it becomes inaccessible. It doesn't matter how it was created.

Comment: Should the developers worry about the objects in braces?

Comment: Of course not. That's the most normal way to create objects.

Comment: So you mean that the objects marked with "()" eg. under the "(system)" or "(closure)" node in the "Constructor" tab are collected by Garbage collector and we don't have to worry about them?

Comment: Clearly I misunderstood you. When you said objects in braces, I thought you meant data created using object literals like `variable = { a:1, b:2 }`. Those are curly braces around the object.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected the question.

Comment: FYI, they're called parentheses. But I think you should make it clear that you're talking about the labels in profiler, not how the objects are notated in code.

Comment: thanks, I guess you're right